# what happens to running/blocked runnables when executorservice is shutdown()

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, executorservice

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017533/does-anyone-see-any-issues-with-this-thread-pattern) about a thread pattern today, and almost everyone suggested that I look into the ExecutorService.

While I was looking into the ExecutorService, I think I am missing something. What happens if the service has a running or blocked threads, and someone calls ExecutorService.shutdown(). What happens to threads that are running or blocked?

Does the ExecutorService wait for those threads to complete before it terminates?

The reason I ask this is because a long time ago when I used to dabble in Java, they deprecated Thread.stop(), and I remember the right way of stopping a thread was to use sempahores and extend Thread when necessary:

```
public void run () {
    while (!this.exit) {
        try {
            block();
            //do something
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }
}

public void stop () {
    this.exit = true;

    if (this.thread != null) {
        this.thread.interrupt();
        this.thread = null;
    }
}
```

How does ExecutorService handle running threads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`ExecutorService#shutdown()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

So it will wait for those threads to complete.

An alternative is the [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

You only need to listen on [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) in the `while` loop inside the `run()` yourself.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation for shutdown() says the thread will be interrupted. The documentation for shutdownNow() suggests that an implementation might interrupt running tasks, but doesn't required it.

Comment: For the avoidance of confusion, I posted my comment before the answer was edited to correctly match the documentation.

Comment: I know. It just annoys me when one person posts a useful answer, another posts an invented truth that happens to have more detail and then later fixes it and gets the credit... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation is pretty clear! From memory, it waits until the threads complete unless you tell it otherwise with, I think, the shutdownNow() method.